# getting code coverage through specflow

Tags: c#, code-coverage, specflow

Coding C#.  Currently using Visual Studo 2013.  We use SpecFlow for BDD.  Need to understand if there is a way to get a code coverage report from SpecFlow directly?  Is there an add on that can get the report through SpecFlow? Or do we have to go to a different testing tool?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to use another tool. We use OpenCover with our SpecFlow tests on our app.